# Redshift while loading parquet data from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, parquet

I am trying to load my parquet file to redshift by using copy command

```
copy i94_data from 's3://<bucket_name>/i94_data_1'
    credentials '<credentials>'
    FORMAT AS PARQUET;
```

Here is schema from my parquet file

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "spark_schema",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "long"
  }, {
    "name" : "cicid",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "visitor_birth_year",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "gender",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "i94_entry_mode_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "insnum",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "airline",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "admnum",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "fltno",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "dtadfile",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "i94visa",
    "type" : [ "null", "double" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "visapost_1",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "occup_1",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "entdepa",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "entdepd",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "matflag",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "arrival_date_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "departure_date_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "country_of_citizenship_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "country_of_residence_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "port_of_entry_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "destination_state_id",
    "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
    "default" : null
  } ]
}
```

Here is my redshift table definition

```
create table if not exists i94_data(id bigint PRIMARY KEY, cicid numeric, visitor_birth_year numeric, gender varchar(10), i94_entry_mode_id bigint, insnum varchar(32), airline text, admnum numeric, fltno text, i94visa numeric, visapost_1 text, occup_1 text,dtadfile text, entdepa text, entdepd text, matflag text, arrival_date_id bigint, country_of_citizenship_id bigint , country_of_residence_id bigint, port_of_entry_id bigint, destination_state_id bigint, departure_date_id bigint)
```

But when I run the copy command, I get the following error

```
ERROR: Spectrum Scan Error Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Spectrum Scan Error code: 15001 context: File 'https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/_xxxxxxxxx has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 's3://_xxxxx/i94_data_1.visapost_1'. Column type: VARCHAR, Parquet sch query: 678 location: dory_util.cpp:1108 process: fetchtask_thread [pid=14218] -----------------------------------------------
```

I have set text for column type visapost_1 which is of type string in parquet. I created Glue Crawler and reviewed the Athena table created and verified that the data is fine but can not figure out why I cannot load it in Redshift.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the table i94_data already exist before you ran CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST?  Any chance this original table is EXTERNAL?  Seems odd to get a Spectrum error if you aren't defining an external table.

Comment: No. That's what is surprising me. This is my table and I have deleted it multiple times. But some how it is treating this table as an EXTERNAL table.

Comment: @MohanHegde Have you tried mentioned the same order of columns in parquet file in the table definition ? I see dtadfile column is not in order in table definition.

Comment: @MohanHegde have you tried correcting the order?

Comment: Thanks, Let me try doing that.